# ios implement unwind action use the code

Tags: ios, navigation

I'm know how to use storybaord drag line to exit use unwind method.

I have four uiviewcontroller (A~D).

I write the code in B UIViewcontroller

```
    -(IBAction) backToMenu:(UIStoryboardSegue *) segue
    {

    }
```

I know It's can drag the action to the green button(exit) to set the back action in the D UIViewcontroller.

It will show the backToMenu method name and they can link.

Now, I want to use programming to implement the drag to green button (exit) action.

But I don't know how to write this part.

I don't use popViewControllerAnimated method. because I need from D UIViewcontroller back to the B UIviewcontroller.

And D UIviewcontroller have a condition if a variable is YES, will unwind to the B(backToMenu) method.

Have any one know how to use the code implement the "drag line to the exit button" action?

(I am use navigation push, not modal)
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should've read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UINavigationController/popToViewController:animated:).

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:vcB animated:YES];
```